# tunnelblick disconnects after every 25sec

Tags: openvpn, svn, tunnel

I have install latest Tunnelblick ( 3.5.5 ) and and also have .ovpn file for configure network on my mac machine.

It's connects only on first attempt. It remain connect as much as i want.

But when i disconnect and try to connect again it disconnect after 20 to 25sec and then keep connect and disconnect.

I need to restart my whole system for make again connection.

Please let me know if any one know about this issue. I think it's just configuration missing issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Logs which i got while disconnect vpn:

> 016-01-30 16:09:42 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process
>   restarting 2016-01-30 16:09:42 MANAGEMENT:
>
> STATE:1454150382,RECONNECTING,ping-restart,, 2016-01-30 16:09:43
>   *Tunnelblick: No 'reconnecting.sh' script to execute 2016-01-30 16:09:43 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release' 2016-01-30 16:09:43 NOTE: the
>   current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call
>   user-defined scripts 2016-01-30 16:09:43 Socket Buffers:
>   R=[196724->65536] S=[9216->65536] 2016-01-30 16:09:43 UDPv4 link
>   local: [undef] 2016-01-30 16:09:43 UDPv4 link remote:
>   [AF_INET]176.34.151.207:1194 2016-01-30 16:09:43 MANAGEMENT:
>   STATE:1454150383,WAIT,,, 2016-01-30 16:09:43 MANAGEMENT:
>
> > STATE:1454150383,AUTH,,, 2016-01-30 16:09:43 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]176.34.151.207:1194, sid=211ef23b 2f2e40ac

**Edited:**

Config file: **test.ovpn**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote  176.34.151.207 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
#persist-key
#persist-tun
ca keys/ca2.crt
cert keys/test.crt
key keys/test.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
mute 20
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
keepalive 10 30
```

Comment: could you post your config file?

Comment: I edited my question.. Please review..

Comment: Try setting your keep alive for keepalive 10 180 and see if it makes any difference. Is the VPN a a private hosted one?

Comment: tried with KeepAlive 10 180 but no difference. Actually VPN configuration is manage by my client. So no idea about it.

Comment: If you set `verb 4` in your config you may get some useful information in your log.